# Google AdMob Verification

Tags: android, ios, admob

So, i have a question on Google AdMob Verification. I have requested for Google AdMob Verification about 5 days ago, and i'm pretty sure it took longer than it should be because of the pandemic.

[image: Google AdMob Verification]

I got an email from Google Ads right away after i setup my payments for Google AdMob. Then, in this morning i got another email from Google Ads and it is about completing my account.

[image: Google Ads Email]

Do i need to complete my Google Ads account for my Google AdMob Verification process? is it important? is this the cause of my Google AdMob is not verificated yet? or it's just because they are decreasing working hours?